# Check all checboxes if they have the same value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my html code:

```
 <ul>
   <li>
  <input name="Services[]" class="form-control" value="Canbeprivatized" id="Canbeprivatized" type="checkbox"><label for="Canbeprivatized">Can be privatized </label>
   </li>
   <li>
   <input name="Services[]" class="form-control" value="Englishspoken" id="Englishspoken" type="checkbox"><label for="Englishspoken">English spoken </label>
   </li>
   <li>
   <input name="Services[]" class="form-control" value="Françaisparle" id="Françaisparle" type="checkbox"><label for="Françaisparle">Français parlé </label>
   </li>
   <li>
   <input name="Services[]" class="form-control" value="Petsallowed" id="Petsallowed" type="checkbox"><label for="Petsallowed">Pets allowed </label>
   </li>
   <li>
   <input name="Services[]" class="form-control" value="Piscine" id="Piscine" type="checkbox"><label for="Piscine">Piscine </label>
   </li></ul>
```

jQuery code:

```
var tab = new Array();
tab = data.services.split(",");// data is values of Checkboxes inserted in create form, so now i need to show it because this is edit form
```

My question is how to check all checkboxes who have values equal to values in tab.
Need your help and thank's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do as follows, iterating on `tab`:

```
for (i = 0; i < tab.length; i++)
  $('input[type=checkbox][value=' + tab[i] + ']').prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: can id add [name="Services[]"] ?

Comment: You can modify the selector as you need to match your checkbox elements. In that case it would go like that: 
`$('input[type=checkbox][name="Services[]"][value=' + tab[i] + ']').prop("checked", true);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to find all `checkboxes` whose value exists in array `tab` then use `.prop()` to set its `checked` property

```
$(':checkbox').filter(function(){
    return tab.indexOf($(this).val()) > -1;
}).prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly this should work

```
var tab = 'Englishspoken,Petsallowed';
tab = tab.split(",");
var $input = $('input');
for (var i = 0; i < $input.length; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < tab.length; j++){
        if ($input.eq(i).val() == tab[j]){
            $input.eq(i).prop('checked', true);
        }
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kdf2cagk/)